# Aggregate Total Based On A Log - SQL

Tags: php, sql

So I have a log where Column A is a list of names. For this example I'll just use fruits:

```
Apple  | 1.99
Apple  | 2.05
Orange | 1.95
Apple  | 1.99
```

How would I go about finding out how many total apples and oranges I have? So Apple would be 3, Orange would come out 1.

Comment: Use GROUP BY and COUNT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select ColumnA, count(*) as Count
from Log
group by ColumnA
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of a `count` function

```
select ColumnA, count(columnA) AS count
from Log
group by ColumnA
```

**OUTPUT**

```
ColumnA | count
----------------
Apple   |  3
Orange  |  1
```